# Application runs one time but crashes the second time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

Hello everyone how are you,
Guys i am working on an app and its really pisssing me out, the app is deployed in the device and runs nicely the first time when i use it but when i stop the execution of the app in the device and then try to run it the next time then  the touch screen hangs up and i am left with a black screen and then i reinstall my app again.

In the viewDidLoad i am using the instance of MKMapView and showing the users current location thats all

Please help me out

Comment: Wow. *gets crystal ball*

Comment: it might be beneficial to load some of your code... i would suggest the code that is run at app start, that way people can actually help.

Comment: There is a bug in your application.  If you fix it, then it will start working again properly.

Comment: lol @ Joe. I would have upvoted it after you would have removed the "hide the bug by clicking a checkbox in your plist" part. Don't take it personally. Disabling functionality that people expect to work is not a good move. And fast app switching is necessary. And until there is a very good reason to enable exit on suspend it's just a bad "solution"

Comment: If you think your answer is good, you should have enough faith in SO that the up votes will outweigh the down votes. If it isn't...

Comment: @Jeremy:well i dont know where the bug is thats why i have uploaded this question to ask experts advice

Comment: @Radix: The point is that you have not posted anywhere near enough information to give a more detailed answer than the one in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be in not properly releasing your map delegate. I assume that since you create your MKMapView in viewDidLoad, you release it in the viewDidUnload, which most likely gets called when you fast switch the app. If you have set delegate for the MKMapView you created, you have to set the map view's delegate = nil before you release the MKMapView.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since your app crashes upon starting, it's probably something in your viewDidLoad. Without the code itself I can't really get into more detail, but do you have any saving/loading code for your app? That might explain why it works the first time but crashes after that.

Comment: In the viewDidLoad i am using the instance of MKMapView and showing the users current location thats all

Answer (score 0):

OK Radix, let's build on @Nichola1024's answer.  Start by commenting out your entire `-viewDidLoad` method entirely.  Does that fix the problem?

If so, then that means it's inside of your `-viewDidLoad` method.  So, next uncomment the entire method, but comment out all of your `MKMapView`-related code and see if it's still crash-y.

If it's not crashing, then you know the error is somewhere in the commented-out code.  Just keep commenting out smaller and smaller sections of the code and you'll get there.

Without seeing your actual `-viewDidLoad` method, this is the best we'll probably be able to give you.